# C#/MonoTouch implement a StopWatch showing time on a label dynamically

Tags: xamarin.ios, stopwatch

Is it possible to implement a stopwatch showing stopwatch values changing on label as watch is running.

I have added stopwatch using following code

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
// Begin timing
stopwatch.Start();

// Stop timing
stopwatch.Stop();
```

How should i show time running on a label ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) instead of a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

```
// create a timer that fires every 10 ms
Timer aTimer = new Timer(10);

// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

aTimer.Enabled = true;

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // update your label here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason it worked. The problem is it is not updating the label with the value. I wonder why? I am using MonoTouch for development where i have an label, i guess it takes  time to update that label created using Interface builder. It says thread started but doesnt update label. Any idea how to deal with it

Comment: you need to include a code sample showing how you are updating the label.  Are you using InvokeOnMainThread to update the UI?

Comment: No I am not using InvokeOnMainThread. It is just the same code you detailed above

Comment: private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {
          // update your label here                                            label1.Text = "value";
}